# getting the correct value in blackjack

Tags: python

I have a question about the sum of the cards dealt. When running the code, it doesn't give you the right amount of the two cards added up, i.e. cards [2, 8] would equal 24.. when it is only 10. What is going on? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Is there anything else that seems wrong? If any of my comments are wrong, please, feel free to correct me!

```
import os

import random

deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14] * 4


def deal(deck):  # deck function
    hand = []


    for i in range(2):
        random.shuffle(deck)  # shuffles deck
        card = deck.pop()  # removes and returns the value back to card
        if card == 11: card = "J"  # sets 11 to jack
        if card == 12: card = "Q"  # sets 12 to queen
        if card == 13: card = "K"  # sets 13 to king
        if card == 14: card = "A"  # sets 14 to ace
        hand.append(card)
    return hand


def play_again():  # ask payer if wants to play again function
    again = raw_input("Do you want to play again? (Y/N) : ").lower()


    if again == "y":  # if answers yes, will give the player more cards
        dealer_hand = []
        player_hand = []
        deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14] * 4  # sets deck to values of cards
        game()
    else:
        print ("Bye!")  # exits program
        exit()


def total(hand):
    total = 0  # start off with total of zero


    for card in hand:  # for the cards you dealt
        if card == "J" or card == "Q" or card == "K":  # if the card is j,q,k it equals 10
            total += 10
        elif card == "A":
            if total >= 11: total += 1  # if the card is an A, if the total is more than 11, it makes the vaue 1
        else:
            total += 11  # makes the value of the ace 1 if the total is greater than 11
    else:
        total += card  # adds up your cards
    return total


def hit(hand):
    card = deck.pop()  # removes and returns the value back to card


    if card == 11: card = "J"  # setting the card number to the face value
    if card == 12: card = "Q"
    if card == 13: card = "K"
    if card == 14: card = "A"
    hand.append(card)
    return hand


def clear():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        os.system('CLS')


if os.name == 'posix':
    os.system('clear')


def print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand):  # funtcion for results of hand
    clear()


    print ("The dealer has a " + str(dealer_hand) + " for a total of " + str(total(dealer_hand)))  # gives you dealers hand
    print ("You have a " + str(player_hand) + " for a total of " + str(total(player_hand)))  # gives you your hand


def blackjack(dealer_hand, player_hand):
    if total(player_hand) == 21:
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)  # prints dealers and your hand
        print ("Congratulations! You got a Blackjack!\n")
        play_again()
    elif total(dealer_hand) == 21:  # if hand is more than 21,
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)  # prints out dealer and your hand
        print ("Sorry, you lose. The dealer got a blackjack.\n")
        play_again()


def score(dealer_hand, player_hand):
    if total(player_hand) == 21:  # if your hand = 21
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)  # shows dealers/ your hand
        print ("Congratulations! You got a Blackjack!\n")
    elif total(dealer_hand) == 21:  # if dealer hand = 21
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)  # shows dealers/ your hand
        print ("Sorry, you lose. The dealer got a blackjack.\n")
    elif total(player_hand) > 21:  # if your hand is greater than
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)  # shows dealers/ your hand
        print ("Sorry. You busted. You lose.\n")
    elif total(dealer_hand) > 21:  # if dealer hand is greater than 21
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)  # shows dealers/ your hand
        print ("Dealer busts. You win!\n")
    elif total(player_hand) < total(dealer_hand):  # if your hand is less than the dealers
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)  # shows dealers/ your hand
        print ("Sorry. Your score isn't higher than the dealer. You lose.\n")
    elif total(player_hand) > total(dealer_hand):  # if your hand is higher than the dealers
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)  # shows dealers/ your hand
        print ("Congratulations. Your score is higher than the dealer. You win\n")


def game():
    choice = 0


    clear()
    print ("WELCOME TO BLACKJACK!\n")  # welcomes player to game
    dealer_hand = deal(deck)  # deals to dealers
    player_hand = deal(deck)  # deals to player
    while choice != "q":
        print ("The dealer is showing a " + str(dealer_hand[0]))  # shows what one of the dealers card is
        print ("You have a " + str(player_hand) + " for a total of " + str(total(player_hand)))  # shows you your hand
        blackjack(dealer_hand, player_hand)  # send inormation to blackjack funciton
        choice = raw_input(
            "Do you want to [H]it, [S]tand, or [Q]uit: ").lower()  # gets user input on if they want to hit, stand, or quit
        clear()
        if choice == "h":
            hit(player_hand)  # adds a new card value to your exisiting han d
            while total(dealer_hand) < 17:  # dealer has to hit is value of cards below 17
                hit(dealer_hand)
            score(dealer_hand, player_hand)
            play_again()
        elif choice == "s":
            while total(dealer_hand) < 17:
                hit(dealer_hand)
            score(dealer_hand, player_hand)
            play_again()
        elif choice == "q":
            print("Bye!")
            exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you pasted has some indentation issues. I fixed that and ran the code, and getting proper results:

```
WELCOME TO BLACKJACK!

The dealer is showing a 5
You have a ['A', 8] for a total of 19
Do you want to [H]it, [S]tand, or [Q]uit: S

The dealer has a [5, 4, 7] for a total of 16
You have a ['A', 8] for a total of 19
Congratulations. Your score is higher than the dealer. You win

Do you want to play again? (Y/N) :
```

Also pasting here the indented code:

```
import os

import random


deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]*4


def deal(deck):  # deck function
    hand = []
    for i in range(2):
        random.shuffle(deck)  # shuffles deck
        card = deck.pop()  # removes and returns the value back to card
        if card == 11:
            card = "J"  # sets 11 to jack
        if card == 12:
            card = "Q"  # sets 12 to queen
        if card == 13:
            card = "K"  # sets 13 to king
        if card == 14:
            card = "A"  # sets 14 to ace
        hand.append(card)
    return hand


def play_again():  # ask payer if wants to play again function
    again = raw_input("Do you want to play again? (Y/N) : ").lower()
    if again == "y":  # if answers yes, will give the player more cards
        dealer_hand = []
        player_hand = []
        deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]*4  #sets deck to values of cards
        game()
    else:
        print ("Bye!")  # exits program
        exit()


def total(hand):
    total = 0  # start off with total of zero
    for card in hand:  # for the cards you dealt
        if card == "J" or card == "Q" or card == "K":  # if the card is j,q,k it equals 10
            total += 10
        elif card == "A":
            if total >= 11: 
                total+= 1  # if the card is an A, if the total is more than 11, it makes the vaue 1
            else: 
                total += 11 # makes the value of the ace 1 if the total is greater than 11
        else:
            total += card  # adds up your cards
    return total


def hit(hand):
    card = deck.pop() # removes and returns the value back to card
    if card == 11:
        card = "J" # setting the card number to the face value
    if card == 12:
        card = "Q"
    if card == 13:
        card = "K"
    if card == 14:
        card = "A"
    hand.append(card)
    return hand


def clear():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        os.system('CLS')
    if os.name == 'posix':
        os.system('clear')


def print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand): # funtcion for results of hand
    clear()
    print ("The dealer has a " + str(dealer_hand) + " for a total of " + str(total(dealer_hand))) # gives you dealers hand
    print ("You have a " + str(player_hand) + " for a total of " + str(total(player_hand))) # gives you your hand


def blackjack(dealer_hand, player_hand):
    if total(player_hand) == 21:
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)  # prints dealers and your hand
        print ("Congratulations! You got a Blackjack!\n")
        play_again()
    elif total(dealer_hand) == 21:  # if hand is more than 21,
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand)   # prints out dealer and your hand
        print ("Sorry, you lose. The dealer got a blackjack.\n")
        play_again()


def score(dealer_hand, player_hand):
    if total(player_hand) == 21: # if your hand = 21
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand) # shows dealers/ your hand
        print ("Congratulations! You got a Blackjack!\n")
    elif total(dealer_hand) == 21: # if dealer hand = 21
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand) # shows dealers/ your hand
        print ("Sorry, you lose. The dealer got a blackjack.\n")
    elif total(player_hand) > 21: # if your hand is greater than
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand) # shows dealers/ your hand
        print ("Sorry. You busted. You lose.\n")
    elif total(dealer_hand) > 21: # if dealer hand is greater than 21
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand) # shows dealers/ your hand
        print ("Dealer busts. You win!\n")
    elif total(player_hand) < total(dealer_hand): # if your hand is less than the dealers
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand) # shows dealers/ your hand
        print ("Sorry. Your score isn't higher than the dealer. You lose.\n")
    elif total(player_hand) > total(dealer_hand): # if your hand is higher than the dealers
        print_results(dealer_hand, player_hand) # shows dealers/ your hand
        print ("Congratulations. Your score is higher than the dealer. You win\n")


def game():
    choice = 0
    clear()
    print ("WELCOME TO BLACKJACK!\n") # welcomes player to game
    dealer_hand = deal(deck) # deals to dealers
    player_hand = deal(deck) # deals to player
    while choice != "q":
        print ("The dealer is showing a " + str(dealer_hand[0]))  # shows what one of the dealers card is
        print ("You have a " + str(player_hand) + " for a total of " + str(total(player_hand))) # shows you your hand
        blackjack(dealer_hand, player_hand)  # send inormation to blackjack funciton
        choice = raw_input("Do you want to [H]it, [S]tand, or [Q]uit: ").lower() # gets user input on if they want to hit, stand, or quit
        clear()
        if choice == "h":
            hit(player_hand) # adds a new card value to your exisiting han d
            while total(dealer_hand) < 17: # dealer has to hit is value of cards below 17
                hit(dealer_hand)
                score(dealer_hand, player_hand)
                play_again()
        elif choice == "s":
            while total(dealer_hand) < 17:
                hit(dealer_hand)
                score(dealer_hand, player_hand)
                play_again()
        elif choice == "q":
            print("Bye!")
            exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game()
```

Let me know if this helped.